# thicken an object of image to a curve in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a labeled matrix containing two objects. How can I thicken an object to a curve? Actually I have the following image:

[image: First Picture]

and I want this:

[image: Second Picture]

Each pixel of the resulting curve is the median of each column. But if you have another idea, it is acceptable, because I want a general scheme of each object as a curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "skeletonization" and you can do it with the function `bwmorph`:

```
bwmorph(Img, 'skel', Inf);
```

Best

Comment: thank you so much, it seems work. but as my first picture has non smooth edge, the result picture is a little different. Then How can smooth the edges?

Comment: A preprocessong with a Gaussian filter would make the edges smoother, for instance.